# Have operators of this kind been studied?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was wandering about an operator of the form $Lf=\sqrt{A^2+B^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}f$.

This would become $Lf\approx B\frac{df}{dx}$ if $B\gg A$ and $Lf\approx Af+\frac{B^2}{2A} \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ if $B\ll A$.

The idea would be to interpolate between a first order operator and a second order operator, somehow. However, I don't even know if this makes actual sense.

Have operators of this form been studied? Can they make sense?

EDIT--------------------------

Ispired by the comment about the Dirac equation.

Maybe I could write $L=\sum_{i\ge 0}a_i\frac{d^i}{dx^i}$, with constant coefficients $a_i$, and impose that $L^2=A^2+B^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. This would give $a_0=A$, the condition $a_0a_1=a_1a_0$ would determine $a_1$, the condition $a_1^2+a_0a_2+a_2a_0=B^2$ would determine $a_2$ and so on.

Such relations could only be satisfied by matrix-valued coefficients, but be that as it may. I would then have an infinite series for the operator $L$, which could in principle be truncated to a desired approximation.

Does this make sense?

Comment: You may find the Dirac equation from physics quite interesting, it approaches a similar question, by ingeniously factoring the square root

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2$ or $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$?

Comment: It is most offen the case  that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is negative because $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{iax}=-a^2e^{iax}$. So you probably want to replace it $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. For an operator with periodic conditions on $[-\pi,\pi]$. $\sqrt{A^2-B^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ne^{inx}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n\sqrt{A^2+B^2n^2}e^{inx}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts or $B$ could be imaginary :)

Comment: @thedude Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ and $B$ might be negative we need to compare the absolute values

- for $|B|\sqrt{\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}}>> |A|$

$$Lf=\sqrt{A^2+B^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}f\approx |B|\sqrt{\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}}$$

- for $|B|\sqrt{\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}}<<  |A|$

$$Lf=\sqrt{A^2+B^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}f=A\left( 1+\frac{B^2}{A^2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^\frac12f \approx Af+\frac{B^2}{2A}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$

Comment: Concerning your first point, I want the square root to be applied before the operator acts on $f$, so I get $\sqrt{D^2_x}f=D_xf$ not $\sqrt{D^2_xf}$.

Comment: Concerning your second point, it should have been $A^2$ inside the root, I have corrected it, sorry.

Comment: @thedude The symbol $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ indicates a second derivative, do you mean$ \left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2$?

Comment: I mean a second derivative, but I *also* mean $\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}=\frac{d}{dx}$. (its not like I *really* know what I am doing, its all very tentative)

Comment: that's $ \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}=\frac{d}{dx}$ absolutely meaningless

Comment: Absolutely meaningless? Are you sure? Maybe one can interpret $\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}$ as a pseudo-differential operator?

Comment: @thedude In this case I'm not an expert about that, sorry I thought you were referring to standard operators.